# SQL not working with ASP classic

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I am trying to add this SQL to a script that will run when the user presses the like button it is meant to add to the like db table, for testing purposes I am using random numbers, however even after making the SQL very simple it still does not work.

The code where this is implemented in the page is  below, it works if I insert into another table such as post.

```
<%
' make VB declare all variables
option explicit

' variable listing and usage
DIM conx ' connection object to the server
DIM comd ' instance of a command object
DIM sql_comd ' string variable to hold the SQL commands
DIM itemsAdded ' numeric var to hold num records added to table (1 or 0)
DIM dbpath  ' path to the database file

DIM pos_TIME 
DIM pos_DATE 
DIM CurrDate


pos_TIME = TIME
CurrDate = Now()
pos_DATE = DATE()    


if NOT ISDate(pos_TIME) Then
    pos_TIME = "00:00:00"
end if

**sql_comd="INSERT INTO like (lik_POSTID, lik_COMMENTID, lik_USERID, lik_DATE, lik_TIME) VALUES(40, 40, 40, 12/4/2013, 12/4/2013)"**
```

Comment: The first thing I'd try is single quotes around your datetime values in your insert query.  Also, what database are you using? If it isn't Access or SQL Server you may have other hoops to jump through.  NB - you don't need empty brackets after Date and Now in vbs  http://www.w3schools.com/vbScript/vbscript_ref_functions.asp

Answer (score 1):

Put some brakets around the like keyword and add quotes around the date :

```
sql_comd="INSERT INTO [like] (lik_POSTID, lik_COMMENTID, lik_USERID, lik_DATE, lik_TIME) VALUES(40, 40, 40, '12/4/2013', '12/4/2013')"
```